# Get Link of Page Selected through a Select Field in Custom Admin Page

Tags: admin, dropdown, select, options

I've created a list of pages in the backend of a Wordpress site using `wp_dropdown_pages();`, which of course shows a dropdown of existing pages. What I'd like to achieve is retrieving not the name but the link of the selected page, so that I can use it as the href of a custom button in the frontend.

I'm very new to creating custom admin options. I got it to working with inputs and textareas using `get_option()`, but I'm not sure how to proceed in this case.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you register your setting like this:

```
function my_awesome_register_fields_for_additional_settings(){
    register_setting('reading', 'my_awesome_pagelink_for_frontend_button');
    add_settings_field('my_awesome_pagelink_for_frontend_button', '<label for="my_awesome_pagelink_for_frontend_button">The Frontend Button shall link to this page:</label>' , 'my_awesome_pagelink_for_frontend_button_html', 'reading');
}

add_filter('admin_init', 'my_awesome_register_fields_for_additional_settings');
```

After that, you define the callback for your settings field:

```
function my_awesome_pagelink_for_frontend_button_html(){
    $option = (int)get_option('my_awesome_pagelink_for_frontend_button',0);
    wp_dropdown_pages(array(
            'selected' => $option,
            'name'   => 'my_awesome_pagelink_for_frontend_button',
            'show_option_none'  => 'Please Choose',
            'option_none_value' => 0, 
                ));
}
```

The wp_dropdown_pages function uses the Page-ID as values, so you're already set.

All you need to do now is to echo your button in the front-end like this:

```
if($buttonlink = (int)get_option('my_awesome_pagelink_for_frontend_button',0)){
      ?><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($buttonlink); ?>" class="button"><?php echo get_the_title($buttonlink); ?></a><?php
}
```

Happy Coding,
Kuchenundkakao

Edit: language.